# Consider a ML application that involves data points characterized by a feature vector  and a numeric label ?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, vector

Consider a ML application that involves data points characterized by a feature vector    and a numeric label   . Which of the following are useful criteria for the quality of a predictor function  ℎ() , which delivers a predicted label  ̂ =ℎ() ?

1.For each predictor function  ℎ∈ , compute the difference  −̂   between the true label    and the predicted label  ̂ =ℎ()  and pick the predictor function with the smallest value of loss.

2.Use the squared error loss  (−̂ )2  and pick a predictor function with a squared error loss larger than  100 .

3.Use the squared error loss  (−̂ )2  and pick the predictor function with the smallest value of squared error loss.

4.Use the squared error loss  (−̂ )2  and pick the predictor function with the smallest value of the squared error loss.

What is the right way to solve this out of 4 options?